# VB "Label is not a type and can not be used as an expression"

Tags: vb.net

First, I have searched using SO and have not found answer.

Program cannot compile due to this build error in which I attempt to use dynamic label.

Here is the offending part of code (how fix this error message)?

```
Label(num).text = userchoice(num) Then
```

Error message:

> Label is not a type and cannot be used as an expresssion

All of the code:

```
Public Class MainForm

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim foodtype As Decimal
    Dim userchoice

    For num As Integer = 1 To 7 Step 1
        If num <= 4 Then
            foodtype = "Main course"
        ElseIf num = 5 Then
            foodtype = "Bread"
        ElseIf num = 6 Then
            foodtype = "Drink"
        ElseIf num = 7 Then
            foodtype = "Dessert"
        End If
        userchoice(num).to = InputBox(foodtype & num)
        Dim lc = userchoice(num).tolower
        Dim calories
        If lc = "stuffing" Then
            calories = 165
        ElseIf lc = "turkey" Then
            calories = 180
        ElseIf lc = "mashed potatoes" Then
            calories = 220
        ElseIf lc = "carrots" Then
            calories = 25
        ElseIf lc = "french bread" Then
            calories = 224
        ElseIf lc = "everclear" OrElse lc = "water" Then
            calories = 1
        ElseIf lc = "pudding" Then
            calories = "170"
        End If
        Label(num).text = userchoice(num) Then
    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I would say, you are missing an If statement in front of the Label(num) and I don't see anywhere a declaration of the Label variable, so it's hard to say what is happening. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Your statement is syntactically incorrect. `<expression> Then` is not a valid statement in Visual Basic.

Comment: @Heinzi what is the correct syntax?

Comment: @ThomasShera: That depends on what that line of code is supposed to do. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @Heinzi take a label of dynamic name and store the value to that. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasShera: And what was the `Then` supposed to do?

Comment: `label(1).Text = ...` isnt the same as `Label1.Text = ...` if that is what you are after. (anf the `Then` is totally out of place)  You cant conjure object references that way.  Turn on Option Strict and more errors will reveal themselves